# PictureBox vs Paint C#

Tags: c#, winforms, paint, picturebox

I am creating an application using WinForms which will potentially have upwards of 100 different images/objects on screen. Is it better to use the Paint event on the form, or have 100 different pictureboxes?

Edit: After some testing, I switched my code to use the Paint event. Thanks for the help everyone!

Comment: What are you trying to do, and what will the picture-boxes be used for?

Comment: It's going to be an application that's essentially a chess game which allows you to connect to another user through sockets. The paint/pictureboxes will be the chess pieces, board, player name, etc.

Comment: So i think you should use the `paint` event.
But I suggest switching to WPF if you are starting a new project..

Comment: Label and PictureBox are the most wasteful controls in the toolbox.  They both can typically be replaced with a single line of code.  You'll get away with it though, you're a bit South of noticing your program painting sluggishly.  If you are doing this because you are developing a chess algorithm then don't get bogged down too much with the UI, that's secondary.  If you are doing this as a coding exercise then by all means implement painting and hit testing in code instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should handle the `Paint` event.
(and make sure to enable double-buffering)

Making large numbers of controls will lead to performance issues.
Also, painting everything yourself allows you to easily use more-complicated effects like transparency.

Alternatively, switch to WPF.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use the Paint event since it has better performance then the PictureBox and its compatible with older .NET, but PictureBox are also pretty useful to show images from resources like .JPEG files.

TIP: If you want to use the same image in multiple PictureBox controls, create a clone of the image for each PictureBox. Accessing the same image from multiple controls causes an exception to occur.